# wpf textblock focus on mouse right click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, textblock

hello I am pretty new to wpf c#, I have a treeview which is populated at run time and  here is my xaml code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="Properties\accessories-text-editor-6.ico" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Green" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseRightButtonDown" >
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="HeadLine" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Textblock" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Author" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="PageNumber" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="RunningTitle" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Illustration" ></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

what I want is when I right click the textblock that is inside the treeview. the textblock need to be focus. As of now what it does is show the context menu item.

so how do I get the index of the Right clicked textblock? so I can focus to that item. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A TextBlock cannot be focused...but you can get a reference to it in the MouseRightButtonDown event handler by casting the sender argument:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock txt = sender as TextBlock;
    //do whatever you want with the TextBlock...
}
```

If you are in the context of a TreeView you may want to select the parent TreeViewItem:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock txt = sender as TextBlock;
    TreeViewItem tvi = FindParent<TreeViewItem>(txt);
    if (tvi != null)
        tvi.IsSelected = true;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: Not sure it helps the OP, but I think `TextBlock` *can* be focused since it inherits `UIElement` (which implement `Focusable` and `IsFocus` dependency properties as well as the `Focus()` method). I just wanted to clarify.